# I couldn't open Eclipse and show error java virtual machine launcher

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to use eclipse-java-2019-03-R-win32-x86_64 with WebSphere 8.5.
when open eclipse it show error "java virtual machine launcher"
I follow up solve method from google 3 method is still unable.

1.Insert variable
Variable name (1): _JAVA_OPTIONS
Variable name (2):  –Xmx512M

2.Run JAVA on Administator

3.Re-install JAVA

Please see error below picture
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGm25.png)

Remark:Eclipse 2023 is can be used normally.

I want to use Eclipse 2019-03R in normally

Comment: Have you modified the eclipse.ini file? -1 usually means invalid arguments, and `--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM` is not a valid argument for Java 1.8.

Comment: What exactly prevents you from upgrading?